# How do I edit a XML file from internal storage in android?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I have been able to write and read from an XML file from the internal storage. However, if i wish to only edit small portion of the XML file, do i really have to read the entire XML file, maybe using XmlPullParser? Was hoping that there might be ways where i don't need to read the entire file out.

Comment: is it true that i can only edit the XML file if i use SAX or DOM parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is DOM parser to write XML file u hav just to read xml file i dont no where you put your XML file...So try to write xml file i just referenced in java.....

http://www.roseindia.net/xml/dom/StoreData.shtml

http://www.roseindia.net/xml/dom/RemoveElement.shtml

Comment: Hoewever, i am using SAX parser to read/write from internal memory however i have to read/write the whole XML file each time. But thanks for the links.